# Existence of a regular element

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $R$ a commutative noetherian ring and $M$ a noetherian $R$-module. An ideal $I \subset R$ contains a $M$-regular element iff $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,M)=0$.

I can prove $(\Rightarrow)$, but I can't prove the other assertion.

Any idea or reference for this?

Remark: $x \in R$ is an $M$-regular element means that $x$ is not a zero divisor in M.

Comment: So a unit in $R$ is not an $M$-regular element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathrm{Hom}(R/I,M)=0$, then there is no nonzero $a \in M$ whose vanishing ideal contains $I$. In other words, the (finite) set of associated primes of $M$ contains no prime ideal containing $I$. By the prime avoidance lemma, the reunion of the associated primes of $M$ does not contain $I$. But the reunion of the associated primes of $M$ is exactly the set of elements of $R$ that aren’t $M$-regular.